# In a Scatter Plot, I'd like to Autofill an Axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am loading data from a text file that is a single column. I want to make a scatter plot with this data, but I only have one axis (the loaded data). For my other axis, I would like to just count up (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5,...) until I have a matching value for every value loaded in.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You can just create it yourself. `x_axis = range(len(y_axis_data))`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sample file `txt`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """4
5
2
6
1
4
3
6
2
7"""

s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=None, squeeze=True)
```

The default index assigned to the series `s` will be `0` to length of series less `1`.  You can reset the index to get it into the dataframe and plot accordingly.

```
s.reset_index(name='x').plot.scatter('x', 'index')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss on how `txt` results in that graph. Some `x` labels have multiple `y` data, others don't. In the case of `x = 4`, What is generating both the `y=0` and `y=5` values?

Comment: @roganjosh we plot both `(0, 4)` and `(5, 4)`  Because `4` is at both the zero'th indexed position and the fifth indexed position.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. From the question I had it in my head that OP just wanted a unique index for every value read in (I don't know the usefulness of the resulting graph in such a case). The question isn't particularly clear.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib automatically uses the index of the y data if no x data is given. So you could simply supply your data array to the plotting function,  `pyplot.plot(data)`

```
import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv = u"13.7\n12.4\n10.1\n7.4\n3.7\n9.4\n8.2"

a = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(csv))
plt.plot(a, marker="o", ls="")

plt.xlabel("index")
plt.ylabel("data")

plt.show()
```

[image]